Apigee EdgeMicro Multi Path
I'm having an issue with apigee edgemicrogateway, I'm trying to create differents route and each route will have differents policies, I have this config file:
edge_config:
  bootstrap: >-
    https://edgemicroservices.apigee.net/edgemicro/bootstrap/organization/someOrganization/environment/dev
  jwt_public_key: 'https://someOrganization-env.apigee.net/edgemicro-auth/publicKey'
  managementUri: 'https://api.enterprise.apigee.com'
  vaultName: microgateway
  authUri: 'https://%s-%s.apigee.net/edgemicro-auth'
  baseUri: >-
    https://edgemicroservices.apigee.net/edgemicro/%s/organization/%s/environment/%s
  bootstrapMessage: Please copy the following property to the edge micro agent config
  keySecretMessage: The following credentials are required to start edge micro
  products: 'https://someOrganization-env.apigee.net/edgemicro-auth/products'
edgemicro:
  port: 8000
  max_connections: 1000
  config_change_poll_interval: 600
  logging:
    level: error
    dir: /var/tmp
    stats_log_interval: 60
    rotate_interval: 24
    stack_trace: false
  plugins:    
    sequence:
      - oauth      
      - policy1
headers:
  x-forwarded-for: true
  x-forwarded-host: true
  x-request-id: true
  x-response-time: true
  via: true
oauth:
  allowNoAuthorization: false
  allowInvalidAuthorization: false
  gracePeriod: 10
  verify_api_key_url: 'https://someOrganization-env.apigee.net/edgemicro-auth/verifyApiKey'
analytics:
  uri: >-
    https://edgemicroservices.apigee.net/edgemicro/axpublisher/organization/someOrganization/environment/env
  bufferSize: 10000
  batchSize: 500
  flushInterval: 5000
proxies:
  - name: edgemicro_some-proxy
    base_path: /my-path
    routes:
      - path: /extra-path/:value
        sequence:
          - policy2
      - path: /other-path/:someValue
        plugins:
          dir: ./someDir
          sequence:
            - policy3
            - policy4

with this configuration, only execute the first sequence, but I need to execute sequence in differents path, but I never go to the path what I want, e.g: myhostname.com/my-path/extra-path/123. In this case the policy never runs and in others cases neither. Please can you help me to fix this issue.
In this case EdgeMicrogateway is running in k8s.
